# Can't find ARCamera in VideoPlayback Unity + Vuforia project

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to create a very basic VideoPlayback AR project using Vuforia and Unity and I can't find the ARCamera. All of the instructions I'm coming across are telling me that it should be under Assets > Vuforia > Prefabs > ARCamera, but it's not there. Does anyone know where else it might be located or if this is a known bug? I'm using Unity version 5.3.5 and Vuforia 6.

Thanks so much!

Comment: did you try re-importing vuforia package?

Comment: I did. I tried twice with the general Vuforia 6 SDK and also tried downloading the specific version I found under "Advanced Topics" that mentions the Video Playback feature.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have a problem with the Unity Version. I was using unity version 2020.1.4f1, Once I tried with version 2019.4.9f1(LTS), I was able to export ARCamera. Go to the Game Object -> Vuforia Engine and select ARCamera.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a folder in Assets called Vuforia? If not, you need to install the asset library by downloading from inside the Vuforia developer portal. If there is a "Vuforia" folder, the library seems corrupt so reinstall. You will need to import the vuforia asset library into every project you start in Unity.

Comment: There is a Vuforia folder, but the camera just wasn't there. It's helpful to know that the library might be corrupt and it's not just a user error on my part. I'm going to try again now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try downloading the below unitypackage. this enables the Vuforia SDK to build Android, iOS, and UWP applications for mobile devices and digital eyewear. Apps can be built with Android Studio, XCode, Visual Studio, and Unity.

https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the issue was some kind of glitch and it resolved itself after I restarted my computer a few times. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you go to **Assets > Vuforia > Prefabs > ARCamera**, click on **Prefabs** folder instead of exploring it. If you explored it then you will only see **SmarTerrian** folder, no ARCamera and other prefabs!